# jQuery Select2 freeze the browser when there are too many select boxes

Tags: jquery-select2

In a form I have thousands of records to update and in each record I have a select box(each select box have 20-30 options) so there are total thousand of select boxes. When I apply Select2 on these all select boxes using same class Its freeze my browser. If I don't use select2 then it works fine.

To reproduce this issue:-

1. create multiple single select boxes (may be 4000) and you can keep 2-3 options in each select box
2. now run this in browser(It will work fine without freezing the browser)
3. Now apply select2 on all select box(It will freeze the browser)
   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried another jQuery plugin also but all have same issue because if we use thousands of select dropdown boxes then its take too much to initialize for all select boxes thats why its freeze the browser.
For this I have initialize select2 either on mouseover(can apply on click also) of the select box so it will not init on load but load for the select boxes we need to apply when we mouseover.

`$(document).on('mouseover', 'select', function() {
    $(this).select2().select2('open');
});`